# Articles choice

Tags: articles

Please help me choose "**the**" or "**0**" for the space

*"My sister often reads _____ fashion pages in the newspapers to keep up with the latest styles"*

Comment: It's a lot more usual, and sometimes mandatory, to include the definite article with expressions like 'read the sports pages', 'in the business pages'; they're defined sections of newspapers etc. Compare 'Look it up in the index.'

Comment: There is no objective way whatsoever to choose one over the other. Either is grammatical, but they mean opposite things.